# Likelihood of a Distribution of Values Occurring Randomly

Tags: excel, statistics

I have a data matrix depicting the number of telephone calls from one telephone to another, all calls are unidirectional. The rows represent days and the columns represent hours. The data is not a sample - it is the full population. Rows are days of the week and columns are one hour blocks of a 24 hour clock. Values in the cells represent the number of telephone calls from telephone A to telephone B for that specific hour.

I would like to have a repeatable measure that enables me to tell my audience that the likelihood of this distribution occurring randomly is <*x*.

I'd like the formula for Excel 2007 or, as a last resort, VBA code.

I've searched and found answers that tell me how to statistically determine the significance of differences between two different data sets but not how to measure for just one data set against a random outcome.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly"? Do you expect the number of calls to be independent of the day, hour? Or do you expect them to follow a certain distribution?

Answer (score 0):

If the total number of calls in a given hour is T, and the total calling population is P; then the number of calls from A to B should be about T/P if "random".  To test whether this is really the case you'd use the Chi-squared test.  I'm afraid I don't have time to give you the full answer - but it'd be the testvalue=sum((observed_i/P - (T/P))^2/(T/P)) where you check the testvalue against the chi-squared table, and you can pick off the probability too.  Excel can calculate these values.  Refer [Chi-Squared Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) for more details.